# Where do I have to put an image in order to use in a Custom HTML img?

Tags: html

I am trying to use custom HTML in a widget and I can't make an `img` tag to work because I have no idea where to store the image.

Where does one store an image inside a WordPress website ? And not by "Upload Image", no. By using FTP. Where exactly do I have to store images so that I can link them to an `img` tag.

Comment: Why not upload image? That would be the default way to store images in WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get img url first upload it to media library, then click on the img you want to use, and see the full url in the img details. see photo attached with a circle around the url of the img.

[image: img uploaded to media]

Comment: Thank you. This works. Is this the only solution ?

Comment: I use this option. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

wordpress by default stores the images in folders by month and year on /wp-content/uploads/folder_named_year_month and the paths to where they are store can be seen in database on the table wp_posts and the thumbenails on wp_postmeta.

check this [article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/where-does-wordpress-store-images-on-your-site/) for more info